# Can twilio video handle broadcasting video to many (live streaming)?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

Creating a service involving broadcasting video from one to many, similar to twitch.tv. Can twilio handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Twilio Video is not designed to broadcast one to many like Twitch. The maximum number of participants in a Twilio Video Group Room is 50 and for a peer to peer Room is 10.

**Edit:**

Twilio has launched [Twilio Live](https://www.twilio.com/live), which is designed for broadcast use-cases. Check it out to see if it works for you.

Comment: It was 2017, and now its 2020 do we still not have this feaature? what could be the approach having that feature along with Twilio? or I drop Twilio over some other solution?

Comment: It’s 2020 now, but that hasn’t changed that Twilio Video is more for collaboration and 1:1 cases than it is for broadcast. If you want to do broadcast video like Twitch you will need to use another product.

Comment: @philnash I am interested to use a broadcasting service to implement a webinar software, do you know any product that could do that ?

Comment: Twilio recently launched a private beta of this, called Twilio Live. Check it out and see if it works for you: https://www.twilio.com/live